# Sample Breakout Game to introduce students who have covered the AP CS A syllabus to Java Graphics:

Tags: java

I am an AP CS A teacher but as the syllabus does not include Graphics this is really my first time in using Java graphics. I am looking to produce a project not far above the realms of the AP CS A syllabus (classes, inheritance, interfaces, abstract) that will give students an insight into how to produce their own simple games using Java graphics.

I have seen many tutorials on the net but so far nothing as simple as this that I can get my head round and actually truly understand.

Any suggestions on how I could improve the code below without getting too complicated?

Notes:
I am not particularly happy with the infinite loops for example.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public class GameTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game pg = new Game();
    }
}
```

```
interface GameObjects {
    
    Ball ball = new Ball(250, 200); 
    Paddle paddle = new Paddle(450, 390);
    Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[2][10];
    
}
```

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener, GameObjects{

    private final int gWidth = 500;
    private final int gHeight = 400;
    private Dimension screenSize;
        
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbGraphics;
    
    private Thread ballThread;
    private Thread paddleThread;
    
    public Game() {
        screenSize = new Dimension(gWidth, gHeight);
        this.setTitle("Let's Play Game!");
        this.setSize(screenSize);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(this);
        
        for (int row = 0; row < bricks.length ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < bricks[0].length ; col++) {
                bricks[row][col] = new Brick((col*50), (100 + (row * 20)));
            }
        }
        
        ballThread = new Thread(ball);
        ballThread.start();
        paddleThread = new Thread(paddle);
        paddleThread.start();
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbGraphics = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbGraphics);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
        
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        ball.draw(g);
        paddle.draw(g);
        
        boolean allBricksGone = true;
        for ( Brick[] row : bricks ) {
            for ( Brick brick : row ) {
                if (brick.getActive()) {
                    brick.draw(g);
                    allBricksGone = false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (allBricksGone)
            System.exit(0);
        
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        
        repaint();
    }   
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        paddle.keyPressed(e);
    }
        
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        paddle.keyReleased(e);
    }
    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ball implements Runnable, GameObjects {
    
    private int xDirection, yDirection;

    private Rectangle ballRect;
    
    public Ball(int x, int y){
        Random r = new Random();
        
        int rXDir = r.nextInt(1);  
        if (rXDir == 0)
            rXDir--;
            
        setXDirection(rXDir);
            
        int rYDir = r.nextInt(1);
            
        if (rYDir == 0)
            rYDir--;
                    
        setYDirection(rYDir);
        
        ballRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 15, 15);
        
    }
    
    public void setXDirection(int xDir){
        xDirection = xDir;
    }
    
    public void setYDirection(int yDir){
        yDirection = yDir;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.fillRect(ballRect.x, ballRect.y, ballRect.width, ballRect.height);
    }
    
    public void collision(){
        if(ballRect.intersects(paddle.getpaddleRect()))
            setYDirection(-1);
            
        for (int row = 0; row < bricks.length ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < bricks[0].length ; col++) {
                if(bricks[row][col].getActive() && ballRect.intersects(bricks[row][col].getbrickRect())) {
                    bricks[row][col].setInactive();
                    setYDirection(-yDirection);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
                
    public void move() {
        ballRect.x += xDirection;
        ballRect.y += yDirection;
            
        if (ballRect.x <= 5)
            setXDirection(+1);
            
        if (ballRect.x >= 480)
            setXDirection(-1);
        
        if (ballRect.y <= 30)
            setYDirection(+1);
        
        if (ballRect.y >= 385)
            setYDirection(-1);
    }
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                move();
                collision();
                Thread.sleep(4);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Paddle implements Runnable{

    private int xDirection;

    private Rectangle paddleRect;

    public Paddle(int x, int y){
        paddleRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 10);
    }
    
    public Rectangle getpaddleRect(){
        return paddleRect;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            setXDirection(-1);
                
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            setXDirection(1);
    }
    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            setXDirection(0);
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xDir) {
        xDirection = xDir;
    }
    
    public void move() {
        paddleRect.x += xDirection;
        if (paddleRect.x <= 10)
            paddleRect.x = 10;
        if (paddleRect.x >= 440)
            paddleRect.x = 440;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(paddleRect.x, paddleRect.y, paddleRect.width, paddleRect.height);
    }
        
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                move();
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Brick {
    
    private int x, y;

    private boolean active;

    private Rectangle brickRect;


    public Brick(int xVal, int yVal){
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
        brickRect = new Rectangle(x, y, 45, 15);
        active = true;
    }
    
    public boolean getActive(){
        return active;
    }

    public Rectangle getbrickRect(){
        return brickRect;
    }

    public void setInactive(){
        active = false;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(brickRect.x, brickRect.y, brickRect.width, brickRect.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to teach students game development, I can't recommend doing it using Swing and AWT. Today there are frameworks such as [LibGDX](https://libgdx.com/) to make games in (the Steam game [Mindustry](https://github.com/Anuken/Mindustry) is made this way for example). Sorry to say it, but no one really uses Swing and JWT these days so I can't really recommend teaching it to students.

Comment: I agree if I was teaching a course dedicated to Games design, but this is just for short end of year projects (after exams), to allow students to produce something more graphical using the Java language and the concepts (classes, inheritance, interfaces, abstract) students have spent all year learning. I am really just looking for suggestions for improvement of the code above but thanks for the tip, I will certainly look into LibGDX if I have to cover Games Design in the future.

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Your GameTest class should invoke the JFrame with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Finally, the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is a great pattern for GUI development and a really good pattern for most development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to lead by example, there are a few things that rub me the wrong way:

- Use an accepted code format. Spaces before opening braces, no new line at the start of a class or method, be *consistent*.
- Grab an installation of Sonar and ask its opinion. There will be dozens of findings.
- Game has side effects in its constructor (starting threads, etc). Don't do this. A constructor should create and initialize the object, and nothing else. Starting the game should go to a start method.
- Interface GameObjects declared members. This is *not* what interfaces are for.
- A subclass of JFrame should be created on the event handler thread. (See swing tutorial.)
- gWidth and gHeight are constants and should be written as GAME_WIDTH and GAME_HEIGHT.
- The Game-constructor uses a funny mix of direct access and this.whatever. Be consistent. I usually take "this." for noise that can be avoided, but opinions may differ.
- System.exit() called from the draw-method makes me cringe. Couldn't you show a "finished - want to play again?" screen or something? Or at least a dialog? This way, the user will not see any difference between a game he won or a program that has crashed.

Comment: *Interface GameObjects declared members. This is not what interfaces are for.* - even worse, members in interfaces actually become `public static final` (can't call them constants because they are mutable and have methods with side effects)

Comment: I am aware of the interface issue but was trying to keep things as simple as possible but yes I get that this is not what interfaces are for. I assume that the solution to this is the event handler you mention? The formatting issues are also a good point but I especially like the idea of a start method. What I don't understand is what you mean by "Sonar"?

Comment: Sorry, that was abbreviated. https://www.sonarqube.org/